# Package biblatex Warning: No "backend" specified, using Biber backend

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, compiling, kile

I am trying to compile a simple tex file but I get this warning and no bibliography printed out:

```
Package biblatex Warning: No "backend" specified, using Biber backend.
```

I am using Kile on Ubuntu 14.04. While the same exact file on another pc with Ubuntu 12.04 is correclty working. What is the problem? How can I solve it?

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian,english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[font={small}, labelfont=bf, hypcap=true]{caption}[2004/07/16]
\usepackage[unicode,colorlinks=true]{hyperref} 
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,maxcitenames=1,maxbibnames=99,sortcites=true,firstinits=true,doi=false,url=false,isbn=false, hyperref]{biblatex}%style=numeric-comp,sorting=none,backend=biber

\renewbibmacro{in:}{% elimina il in nella biblio
  \ifentrytype{article}{}{%
  \printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}} 

\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\small}

\bibliography{biblioTC}

\title{My paper title}
\author{Me} 
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\newpage

\section{Test}

Lalalalalalalalalala \cite{Colitti2014}.

\newpage
\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\refname}      


\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: With biblatex, ou shouldn't write `\bibliography{biblioTC}`, but `addbibresource{biblioTC.bib}`. That said, did you run the chain: `(pdf)latex > biber > (pdf)latex > (pdf)latex`?

Comment: With Kile on the other pc works also with `\bibliography`. Anyway I tried with `\addbibresource` and I get that the .bbl file is in the wrong format - expected 2.3. I guess the problem is in the compiler or in the settings or installation of bibtex.

Comment: Following up on Bernards comment, have you processed as in http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/15925 ?

Answer (score 7):

It's just a warning, which tells you, you didn't set a backend to manage your bibliography, so biblatex uses the fallback `biber`.

If you want to get rid of the message, you can choose manually between `bibtex`, `bibtex8`, `bibtexu` and `biber`. Just add `backend=xxx` in your biblatex line.

Since you didn't modify the code (and hence your outcommented string says it), you should add `backend=biber`.

See manual, §3.1.1.

**UPDATE:**

Your error log is not complete. Next time please provide the full error log and the needed bib file (biblioTC.bib).

If I compile, I also get following lines:

```
Package biblatex Warning: Conflicting options.
(biblatex)                'firstinits' conflicts with 'uniquename=full'.
(biblatex)                Setting 'uniquename=init' on input line 23.
```

That comes because your chosen style `authoryear-comp` automatically sets `uniquename=full` which interferes with your manual `uniquename=init`.
If you remove this setting as well, you should get rid of that message, too.

Comment: It is just a warning, but it does not print the biblio in the end. I tried to specify which backend to use and I still get empty bibliography.

Comment: Even if I remove the option, I get empty bibliography. So it is not a problem of conflicting option.